# `adb shell input text` stopped working on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

Recently I've been using the `adb shell input text "<text>"` to paste text into my Android emulator quickly. For some reason it stopped working today, when I run the command it seems to succeed (no error messages) but nothing happens on the emulator. Things were working fine on this same emulator a couple days ago and I can't think of anything I changed.

The Android emulator is a Nexus 5X running API 18 (4.3), if it matters. I have to be on this older version of Android to debug an issue with an app on Android 4.3.